# Replacing letters in a String, but not the letters that have been already replaced

Tags: java, string, replace

So I am making a program that will encrypt a message and then decrypt it.

Here is my encryption code:

```
 private static String encrypt(String str){
        String string = str.toLowerCase();
        String string1 = string.replace('a', 'c');
        String string2 = string1.replace('b', 'v');
        String string3 = string2.replace('c', 'n');
        String string4 = string3.replace('d', 'm');
        String string5 = string4.replace('e', 'u');
        String string6 = string5.replace('f', 'd');
        String string7 = string6.replace('g', 'o');
        String string8 = string7.replace('h', 'l');
        String string9 = string8.replace('i', 'p');
        String string10 = string9.replace('j', 'e');
        String string11 = string10.replace('k', 'q');
        String string12 = string11.replace('l', 'k');
        String string13 = string12.replace('m', 'a');
        String string14 = string13.replace('n', 't');
        String string15 = string14.replace('o', 'j');
        String string16 = string15.replace('p', 'f');
        String string17 = string16.replace('q', 's');
        String string18 = string17.replace('r', 'g');
        String string19 = string18.replace('s', 'w');
        String string20 = string19.replace('t', 'b');
        String string21 = string20.replace('u', 'y');
        String string22 = string21.replace('v', 'i');
        String string23 = string22.replace('w', 'x');
        String string24 = string23.replace('x', 'r');
        String string25 = string24.replace('y', 'z');
        String string26 = string25.replace('z', 'h');

        return string26;
    }
```

Take the letters h and i for example. If you look at my notes and the code you may think it should output: "lp" But, because if you look closely after the 'h' to 'l' to 'i' to 'p' the 'p' and the 'l' are again switched. no matter how I move around the numbers in the decryptor, I cannot match this system, with some words it works but with others it doesn't.

I'm looking for a way for the system to know that it already editted that letter and skip it, does anyone have ***ANY*** ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, your new character keeps getting replaced by the subsequent string.replace calls. Instead you could do something like this:

```
 private static String encrypt(String str){
    String string = str.toLowerCase();
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = string.charAt(i);

        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'h':
            {
                string = string.substring(0,i)+"l"+string.substring(i+1);
                break;
            }
            case 'i':
            {
                string = string.substring(0,i)+"p"+string.substring(i+1);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a-z");
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return string;
}
```

The above code will find each character and then replace it, but not go back to re-replace the already replaced character.

Comment: I looked through your code and this is my thought. Say you are running "hi" with what you have right now. Is it just me or will it make it this:
string = "hi"; you get "h" + "l" + "i" = hli? So with just the first case you have hli(assuming it didn't pick up the l as the second character?) I just simply don't get it I'm sorry if I am stupid.

Comment: No no, So say it finds 'h', it will create a substring from the index of h + 1 to start from the next term and then append it to 'l'. I'm essentially replacing the character by creating a string with all terms before the term to be replaced and adding the new character followed by the remaining letters in the String. I hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a character array that holds the encrypted version of characters `a` to `z`.

```
char [] encryptChars = new char[]{'c', 'v', .... 'h'};

private static String encrypt(String str){
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String s = str.toLowerCase();
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        stringBuilder.append(encryptChars[c - 'a']); 
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

The `encryptChars` holds the encrypted chars for `a` to `z` **in order**.
An assumption here is that the source string will only have the characters from set `[A-Za-z]`. If they have any other ASCII character, you need to handle them in the *for* loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the code has now finished the replacement but it will change it again because the code is continuing the code until it reaches the `return` line.

Ex:

I've input the String `Test`, the system then runs until it saw this line `String string20 = string19.replace('t', 'b');`, which meant that the letter `t` is turned into `b`, but the system doesn't even care about what letter is first and last, it checks the whole String `Test` if there is any.

If I do this

```
String oldString = "test";
String newString = oldString.replace("a", "b").replace("b", "c").....replace("y", "z");
System.out.println(newString);
```

The output is this:

```
zzzz
```

But if you want the answer, check out the other answers, this answer is just explaining your code.

Comment: Yes, I get what you mean. I got my code, but I was just trying to find a solution on how to make it where it skips over the ones already replaced. Thank you.

Comment: I'm just explaining what is wrong in your code, I've also said `check out the other's answers`, just so you know that the others have the right answer, I'm just explaining to you.